# .NET projection (CRS conversation) library

Tags: c#, .net, gis

Is there any open-source library exist to calculate coordinate conversions from a CRS (coordinate reference system) to another?

Answer (score 2):

I would look into Proj.NET. A fork of it is maintained in [NetTopologySuite](http://code.google.com/p/nettopologysuite/), which provides you with other spatial functionality.

Another option is to look at DotSpatial with its library [DotSpatial.Projections](http://dotspatial.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=DotSpatial.Projections&referringTitle=Documentation).

Both are ported from the proj4 C++ library.

If you want to convert entire files then I would go with the GDAL/OGR tooling. Easy installation for this is provided by [OSGeo4W](http://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/). Note that there also GDAL/OGR .NET bindings available.

Answer (score 0):

Look for conversion to ECEF (Earth Centered, Earth Focused) conversions. You would take your point in system A, covert to ECEF X,Y,Z from earth center, then convert that to system B.

I don't know of a specific library to recommend. There are lots of results on Google. Just hoping to give you a good direction to start your search.

Answer (score 0):

check our [gdal/ogr](http://www.gdal.org/)
Idont use it with .NET but i think it should work